# How does this program accept data without knowing its datatype?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is a program that checks what kind of input is available via the System.in Input Stream and decides what datatype of a variable to store it in. The code of the program is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hasNextNumberDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your Data :");
        if(in.hasNextInt())
            System.out.println("You have entered an Integer as : " + in.nextInt());
        else if(in.hasNextFloat())
            System.out.println("You have entered an Float Value as : " + in.nextFloat());
        else if(in.hasNextDouble())
            System.out.println("You have entered an Double Value as : " + in.nextDouble());
        else 
            System.out.println("Token not an Integer or a real value.");
   }
}
```

Here, we clearly see that the data can be accepted via multiple points : `in.nextInt()` or `in.nextFloat()` or even `in.nextDouble()`, but all are preceded by a statement to check the datatype of the input (which is yet to be entered [via `hasNextInt()` or `hasNextFloat()` or `hasNextDouble()`]).

My question is how does the program decide what datatype the next token is BEFORE accepting the data?

Further, if `hasNextInt()` or `hasNextFloat()` or `hasNextDouble()` triggers the input of data, rather than `in.nextInt()` or `in.nextFloat()` or  `in.nextDouble()`, then how come there aren't 3 prompts to input the data for the 3 different function calls (of `hasNextInt()` and `hasNextFloat()` and `hasNextDouble()`)?

Comment: I think that these `has..` methods are clearly waits for some input to have, in order to act on it and decide what's type of data it is.

Comment: It is not. '.hasNextInt' for exmaple, simply checks whether the user input can be interpreted as an Int **after the user has provided the input**. Simple google search - [hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scanner will try to parse the next input and if that succeeds the data type fits.

As an example have a look at the implementation of `hasNextFloat()`:

```
public boolean hasNextFloat() {
    setRadix(10);
    boolean result = hasNext(floatPattern());
    if (result) { // Cache it
        try {
            String s = processFloatToken(hasNextResult);
            typeCache = Float.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(s));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see there are several steps involved:

1. Check whether the input matches the pattern for floats, i.e. does it *look* like a float?
2. If the input looks like a float, try to parse it. If that fails it wasn't a float, if it works it is *at least* a float (could be a `double` or even an `int` as well, that's why the code you posted checks for int, float and double in that order).

Comment: What I don't understand is how the three different hasNext____() calls doesn't spawn three different inputs.

Ref : Further, if hasNextInt() or hasNextFloat() or hasNextDouble() triggers the input of data, rather than in.nextInt() or in.nextFloat() or  in.nextDouble(), then how come there aren't 3 prompts to input the data for the 3 different function calls (of hasNextInt() and hasNextFloat() and hasNextDouble())?

Comment: What I mean is, I call all 3 of _hasNextInt()_, _hasNextFloat()_ and _hasNextDouble()_ functions. So how come I'm not prompted to enter data 3 different times?

Comment: @SomenathSinha if you take a further look at the code you'll see that `hasNextXxx()` will only read input if needed, i.e. it will read user input once and all calls to those methods will operate on that input until it is consumed, e.g. by calling `next()`.

Answer (score 1):

The very first `if(in.hasNextInt())` will wait until you press enter. It and all subsequent `has`-methods will work with that line of input until a `next`-method consumes it.

`hasNext()` can not be decided without the scanner either having a line of input, or the "end of stream". Console input has no end, so `hasNext()` will eventually be `true`. But scanner can't know for sure until there is a line of text in it's buffer as proof.

You can rewrite the code you have as

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your Data :");
    String next = in.next();
    if (isInt(next))
        System.out.println("You have entered an Integer as : " + parseInt(next);
    else if(isFloat(next))
        System.out.println("You have entered an Float Value as : " + parseFloat(next));
    else if(isDouble(next))
        System.out.println("You have entered an Double Value as : " + parseDouble(next));
    else 
        System.out.println("Token not an Integer or a real value.");
```